# 401 on Http request for TMDB API

Tags: javascript, vue.js, http-status-code-401

I am building a movie app project using TMDB API... now when I'm calling for details of the movie using movie id it is showing a 401 error... if anyone can tell what the error is & what's the solution.

[image: the error is coming from methods in fetching moive]

from this component
https://github.com/ShahabDadKhan/movie-app/blob/master/src/components/Moviecard.vue

I am passing the movie id in this component
https://github.com/ShahabDadKhan/movie-app/blob/master/src/views/MovieDetail.vue

Comment: 401 is Unauthorized, you need to send some credentials, like api key. Checkout:
Check out: https://www.themoviedb.org/documentation/api

Answer (score 1):

In general 401 is unauthorized

Anyways the api you use they provide multiple reasons for 401 status code

Go through the list of reasons for 401 in this link below

https://www.themoviedb.org/documentation/api/status-codes

Comment: Yes on further search i found that it is showing this error in my console {"status_code":7,"status_message":"Invalid API key: You must be granted a valid key.","success":false}     even though I have a valid API key which is I'm using to fetch movie and it is working but it is not forworking for fetching the details of the movie

Comment: Just now I saw your git repo... For movie detail component you made api call without providing api_key as a url parameter.. may be that is the reason you got 401 for fetching details
https://developers.themoviedb.org/3/getting-started/append-to-response
Here they asked to provide api_key in the url

Answer (score 0):

First you might wanna try to example themovieapp API query from the tmdb settings page.

If that work there is no problem with API key.

I had the same issue. It occurred when I tried to use my API key via .env file.

Restarting serves does the trick. Try to close all terminals and re-start with npm-start.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30954812)

Answer (score 0):

First try adding the key directly here (Just to see if the problem comes from the KEY):

```js
//API
fetch(
  `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key= LONG CODE HERE&language=en-US&page=1&include_adult=false&query=${e.target.value}`
)
  .then((res) => res.json())
  .then((data) => {
    console.log(data);
  });
```

If it works and you get the movie results, the problem comes from somewhere else in your app.

Some reasons why it might not work:

- a space inside the .env
- the .env file is not in the root directory

```js
    //API
    fetch(
      `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key=${process.env.REACT_APP_TMDB_KEY}&language=en-US&page=1&include_adult=false&query=${e.target.value}`
    )
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => {
        console.log(data);
      });
  };
```